# If $R$ is a ring and $R^n$ and $R^m$ are isomorphic as left $R$-modules then they are also isomorphic as right R$-modules

Tags: abstract-algebra, modules, free-modules

Is it necessarily true that if $R$ is a ring and $R^n$ and $R^m$ are isomorphic as left $R$-modules then they are also isomorphic as right $R$-modules.

It appears as if they are.

Comment: Interestingly enough, in the commutative case this implies $n=m$ assuming both are finite (simply quotient out at a maximal ideal).

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Yes. For this to have content, $R$ must be non-commutative, and non-Noetherian.

If $\phi:R^m\to R^n$ is a left $R$-module isomorphism,
and $\psi:R^n\to R^m$ is its inverse, then they correspond
to matrices $A$ and $B$ over $R$ with $AB=I_m$ and $BA=I_n$.
But then $A$ and $B$ correspond to right $R$-module maps $R^n\to R^m$
and $R^m\to R^n$ which are inverse to each other.

Comment: Actually, isn't this an example of 'duality in action' in category theory? Something along the lines of 'for every result you get the dual result for free' - sorry, I'm at work and can't look this up at the moment.

Comment: A ring is said to have *invariant basis number* if $R^m\cong R^n$ (as left modules) implies $m=n$; your argument shows the notion is right-left symmetric. If $f\colon R\to S$ is a surjective ring homomorphism and $S$ has IBN, then also $R$ has IBN (which implies every commutative ring has IBN). The easiest example of a ring without IBN is $\operatorname{End}_F(V)$, where $V$ is an infinite dimensional vector space over the field $F$.

Comment: @j4nd3r53n No, this isn't a category theory duality. Some ring properties are not left-right symmetric: for instance a ring may be left perfect (every left module has a projective cover) but not right perfect.

Comment: Damn! :-) Thanks for pointing this out, @egreg. I suppose it's good to know that not every result comes directly from category theory.